# Can Not find static text control when the test is executed on virtual machine

Tags: testing, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am using Microsoft Automation UI framework to develop my automation test cases. The problem I faced with is related to interaction with static text control. I am just trying to get the control's text. The test work perfect when I run the test on my local machine. The problem is when I run the test via Test Controler on the (no matter which) Test Agent. The error which appear is that the static control text can not be found.

Theis is the part of my code where I am trying to initialize the control I want to interact with:

```
    private void Init(TreeScope treeScope, params Condition[] properties)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Condition> propertiesList = properties.ToList();
            propertiesList.Add(Condition.TrueCondition);

            bool controlFound = Wait.ForCondition(
                () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        TestControl = Parent.FindFirst(treeScope,
                            new System.Windows.Automation.AndCondition(propertiesList.ToArray()));
                        return !TestControl.Current.IsOffscreen;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            if (!controlFound)
            {
                throw new ElementNotAvailableException(DescriptiveName + "Control is NOT found");
            }

            this.GetItAsUITestControl().WaitForControlReady(Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyTimeout);
            if (TestControl.Current.IsKeyboardFocusable)
            {
                TestControl.SetFocus();
            }

            string controlFullName = this.TestControl.Current.ControlType.ProgrammaticName;
            DescriptiveName = "< " + DescriptiveName + " " + controlFullName.Substring(controlFullName.LastIndexOf(".")) + " >";


        }
        catch (ElementNotAvailableException ex)
        {
            Report.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Report.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

I am using Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 for managing my virtual machines (I think all machines are vmware). But from my prespective the problem is not in the virtual machine because all of the tests are executed without any problems on the VM except the one which verify the Static Text Control content. I am 100% sure that the desctop of the VM where the tests are executed is active because I am able to look at it using VMWare Remote Console.

In terms of execution of the tests on the remote machine I am using Test Controlers and Test Agents which comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the VM that you are running the test under? UIAutomation requires an interactive desktop to work, so won't work if the VM is 'disconnected', for example. (I'm also assuming that both the target app and the test code are on the VM, since UIA can't see "through" a VM.)

Comment: Active desktop throws a specific error so it is unlikely to be the problem.